# Taking char type name using getline in structure

Tags: c++

As I declared a structure array: struct name data[5];
When I try to take input using cin.getline(data[i].full_name,75) (which I need) then after first time it skips the char input. I searched on this site and used fgets but was of no use.
 The code is :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct name
{
   char full_name[75];
   int number; 
};

void input(struct name data[])
{
   int i=0;
   while(i<5)
   {
      cout<<"Enter the name: ";
      fgets(data[i].full_name,75,stdin);
                   OR
      cin.getline(data[i].full_name,75)


      cout<<"Enter the number: ";
      cin>>data[i].number;
      i++;
   }
}

int main()
{
    int times=0;
    struct name data[5];
    input(data);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

here is my suggestion hope it helps:

```
void input(struct name data[])
{
   int i=0;
   int number;
   char asciNumber[75];
   while(i<5)
   {
      cout<<"Enter the name: ";      
      cin.getline(data[i].full_name,75);     
      cout<<"Enter the number: ";
      cin.getline(asciNumber,75);     
      try
      {
          number = atoi(asciNumber);
          data[i].number = number;
      }
      catch (...)
      {
          //cout << "error in number parsing" << endl;
          // i think its important to check validity of std input\
      }
      i++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, you can't use `fgets`() here, at all. The results of mixing the C library's `stdin`-based functions, and C++ library's `std::cin` are undefined.

But your real problem is this:

```
cin>>data[i].number;
```

Your intent here is to read a line of text containing a number.

As you know, each line of text is terminated by a newline.

The `>>` operator will read the entered number, but it will not actually read the newline character that follows it.

As a result of that, on the next iteration of the loop:

```
cin.getline(data[i].full_name,75)
```

All this will do, then, is immediately read the newline character after the entered number, instead of the next line of text.

You will need to replace your usage of the `>>` operator with another `getline`() that reads the next line of text into a `std::string`, and then use `std::istringstream` to convert it to a number.

That's the cleanest implementation. There are a couple of other possibilities, such as manually reading past the newline character after the number, or another, throw-away call to `std::getline`().